# identityserver4 login authentication with email confirmation

Tags: identityserver4

When I authenticate a user through Identity Server 4, it still authenticates even if `email confirmation = false`.

What am I supposed to do in order to only authenticate if `email confirmation = true`?

Comment: Be more descriptive and show some more code, so that people can understand and help.

Comment: How do you authenticate your user? Can you post your `AccountController.cs` please?

Comment: Did you managed to implement this? i want it too :)